# Can't install software with the "Add/Remove Software" graphical interface, nothing happens

Tags: software-installation, apt, pixel

Running a freshly installed Raspberry Pi OS Desktop on a Raspberry Pi 4, I'm trying to install software using the graphical *Add/Remove Software* tool. For example, Visual Studio Code. After checking the tick near the *code* entry, I clicked *OK*. A popup appears that additional confirmations are needed because other software has to be changed:

[image]

I confirmed with *Weiter* (which means *continue*) but nothing happens. The list appears again and it seems that nothing is working on installing the software, there is no CPU/Network/IO usage.

[image]

This doesn't change after waiting for a few minutes. The `code` command is also still not avaliable.

Using `sudo apt install code` on the commandline works, about a minute later VS Code is avaliable using the `code` binary as well as in the application menu of the pixel desktop:

[image]

The same happens on other packages like `vim`: The GUI doesn't do anything, installing using the terminal works perfectly. I tried to run the *Add/Remove software* gui using the `pi-packages` command from the terminal, in hope to get some information, but I only get the following lines immediately after startup (without doing anything in the UI):

```
$ pi-packages

(pi-packages:5577): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 16:11:10.005: gtk_widget_get_style_context: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(pi-packages:5577): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 16:11:10.005: gtk_style_context_add_class: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_CONTEXT (context)' failed
```

I found [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=132620) and changed the locales back to `en_GB.UTF-8` (since they were German). After the reboot, the behaviour is still the same.

#### Why is the GUI not working? What's the problem?

EDIT

I found the `-v` switch and after clicking continue, it gave me the following entry

```
GnomePackageKit     failed to install packages: Failed to obtain authentication.
```

This seems strange, I never got an authentication popup - also not behind the window. I tried to allow sudo without password in `visudo` with the line

```
pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Still doesn't work.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt update` in a terminal window and respond to any questions, If that succeeds you can try installing programs in the GUI again.

Comment: @Dirk I did that: _All packages are up to date_. But I'm wondering why update shoud ask questions, I only remember this from upgrade. I also ran `apt upgrade`, which also says that everything is up2date.

Comment: There is a recent 'issue' introduced with release of Debian/Raspbian update to Bullseye. Some (not all) users had to acknowledge that Buster is now 'oldstable' during the update otherwise the process would not progress.

Comment: I found out that this problem seems caused by using a RDP connection: `xrdp` was installed on the client and I used it to access the GUI from my workstation PC. After connecting the PI to a physical screen, mouse and keyboard, it shows an authentication dialog and now it works 

Comment: Pls add that as an answer so that other users can solve similar problems

Comment: I will still do that, I'm currently creating a bug report in hope it will get fixed in the long term and then link everything together :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that this issue is limited to remote sessions, like done with `xrdp`. When using a screen with keyboard/mouse physically connected to the PI, it shows a authentication dialog. After providing my password, the installation was started.

We're curretly [investigating this in a GitHub issue](https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/2000). As workaround, you can access your Pi physically if the GUI is a requirement for you, or alternatively use the commandline with the known commands like `apt install`.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem with PiPackages and it persist. I am logged from local machine (Raspberry Pi 400), and can't find any clues.

PiPackage stopped asking me for password and simply shows that it is installing software. But with no result.

In shell I can use apt and it works as it should work, without any problems. All the programs are installed properly.

Package log from graphical interface (Options -> Package log...) shows that software was installed but actually it wasn't.

Can this be related to installing and removing snapd?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/130610)

Answer (score 0):

I tried also reinstalling Pi-Packages and anything and found the problem - somewhat (IDK and have no clues) disabled LXPolKit auth daemon. So I enabled it again, restarted and installation software started to work again.

BTW it seems that Synaptic Package Manager is quite better, because Pi-Packages is not updated for a while and lost forever. Even their website (mentioned in "About" window) is owned by spammers.

[image: Policykit Authentication Agent]